# Where is the python library of QGIS 2.8

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

where is the Python library for QGIS 2.8 on a mac (10.10)?
I cannot find it... 
`sys.path` in the QGIS python console gave me some path, but where the interesting part is happening it replaces the folder with dots.

`'/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing'` and `'/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python`

I need to set my python path to use the QGis.core library which requires the Path.
I got the instruction from this site http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html but it seems not be up to date anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QGIS for Mac ([KyngChaos version](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis)) is an [application bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundle_%28OS_X%29#OS_X_application_bundles) ( directory) and the content of QGIS.app is:

[image]

The path of the modules is

```
  /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python
```

The path of the qgis library is

```
  /Application/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/qgis
```

And of the processing module, for example:

```
 /Application/QGIS.app//Contents/Resources/python/plugins/processing
```

If you want to call qgis from outside (in the console, for example), you have two solutions:

1) Define the variables/paths outside Python (Bash)

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Applications/Qgis.app/Contents/Resources/python
# you can add other modules 
export PYTHONPATH=/Applications/Qgis.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins:$PYTHONPATH
(export PYTHONPAH=/Users/you/.qgis2/python/plugins:$PYTHONPATH if you want)
```

and

```
python
.....
from qgis.core import *
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
# initialize the app
app = QgsApplication([],True)
layer = QgsVectorLayer('/Users/Shared/test.shp', 'test', 'ogr')
layer.isValid()
True
print QgsApplication.showSettings()
Application state:
QGIS_PREFIX_PATH env var:       
Prefix:     /Application/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS
Plugin Path:        /Application/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../PlugIns/qgis
Package Data Path:  /Application/QGIS.app/MacOS/../Resources
Active Theme Name:  
Active Theme Path:  :/images/themes//
Default Theme Path: :/images/themes/default/
SVG Search Paths:    /Application/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/svg/
User DB Path:   /Application/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/resources/qgis.db
# import a module
import processing
print processing.__file__
/Application/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins/processing/__init__.pyc
```

2) Define the paths in Python

```
python
....
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/Applications/QGis.app/Contents/Resources/python/')
sys.path.append('/Applications/QGis.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins')
....
```