# QGIS 2.18 python error

Tags: python-2.7, error, qgis-2.18, file-path

I very new to all the python-QGIS issue. I try to run this one line code in order to know if the PYTHON 2.7 recognize the modules of QGIS:

```
import qgis.core
```

and got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\desktop\test1.py", line 1, in <module>
import qgis.core
ImportError: No module named qgis.core
>>>
```

i red

http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#python-plugins

[Where is the python library of QGIS 2.8](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140692/where-is-the-python-library-of-qgis-2-8)

but didn't understand what should i do?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129959/problem-with-import-qgis-core-when-writing-a-stand-alone-pyqgis-script/130102#130102

Comment: I've tried this solution- with no success.

Comment: GermánCarrillo's answer works for me.