# Plugins repository is unavailable

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, qgis-2, repository, ssl-error

I'm using QGIS 2.18.20. On MacOS High Sierra 10.13.5
Only recently I haven't been able to find uninstalled plugins. The settings show the repository is "unavailable". 
I'm not using a proxy. I've tried using http:// instead of https:// but it comes up with SSL error.

I've manually downloaded the desired plugins (Animove and Point Sampling Tool) but I can't find the .qgis folder on my mac (perhaps this is a lack of knowledge about macs so please advise on this mac users!) so I'm not sure how to go about manually adding the unzipped files

Comment: Same as Faramarz, I had to activate the proxy and it works now! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Managed to figure this out after lots of searching through this site:

1. Manually download the plugin you are looking for (e.g. from here https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pointsamplingtool/) 
   NB: make sure you select the right version for your version of QGIS
2. Drag and drop the whole (unzipped) downloaded file to the following location (this will only be correct for QGIS2):
   MacHD/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins

These posts were very helpful:

- [Plugin not available : point sampling tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198111/plugin-not-available-point-sampling-tool?rq=1)
- [Where is the python library of QGIS 2.8](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140692/where-is-the-python-library-of-qgis-2-8)

Comment: for linux user and qgis 2.8 the content goes here: `/home/YOR_USERNAME/.qgis2/python/plugins/openlayers_plugin` (I needed to create the folder)

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to access https:// via the default library url in March 2019. However I added link via http:// and after ignoring SSL error message plugins listed as they should be using the http url ,however the SSL error stops them being downloaded. They can be accessed through Safari

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reconnect with plugin server on mac after changing URL to https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins and clicking "Ok".

[image]

Comment: No, doesn't work for me, even though there is clearly a web page at that address.In fact QGIS won't let me edit the URL of the listed repository and Add-ing a new one didn't do the trick either. It still shows up as "unavailable".

Answer (score 1):

For Linux the following helped: `install qgis-server python-qgis qgis`

```bash
# Debian-based, as e.g. Ubuntu    
if [ -f "/etc/debian_version" ]; then
    sudo apt install qgis-server python-qgis qgis
fi

# Red-Hat-Based, as e.g. Fedora:
if [ "$(grep -Ei 'fedora|redhat' /etc/*release)" ]; then
    sudo dnf install qgis-server python-qgis qgis
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

esto lo pude resolver de la siguiente manera:
configuraciones, luego en opciones y alli nos vamos a dirigir a  la seccion de red vamos a desactivar la casilla que dice usar proxy para acceso a web. y de esta manera se soluciona el problema

I was able to solve this in the following way:
settings, then in options and there we are going to go to and in the network section we are going to deactivate the box that says use proxy for web access.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer from CamiloAndres worked for me! But in my case I had to activate the checkbox and use the default proxy as proxy type in order to establish a connection to the plugin repository.